# How to call an external method from within an MVEL expression?

Tags: mvel

I have a JAVA class that has two methods. The first one is the main method and the second one is method1().

Let's say the following is the class:

```
public class SomeClass() {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    MVEL.eval("System.out.println(\"I am inside main method\");method1();");
  }
  public static void method1(){
    System.out.println("I am inside method 1");
  }
}
```

Now when I run the program, I get the following output:-

I am inside main method

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: no such method or function: method1]
[Near : ... main method"); method1(); ..}]
                                    ^
[Line: 1, Column: 184]
at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.getMethod(PropertyAccessor.java:898)
at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.getNormal(PropertyAccessor.java:182)
at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.get(PropertyAccessor.java:146)
at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.get(PropertyAccessor.java:126)
at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValue(ASTNode.java:187)
at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:106)
at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:49)
at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:136)
at mypackage.SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:15)
```

As you can see, it prints the first sop, but when it comes to calling method1, it throws exception.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: @MikeBrock Could you please help me out?

Comment: @bradhouse: Could you please let me know if this is even possible?

Comment: @ankur-singhal provided answer works out for me but i am unable to upvote it (i need to gain some 15 points reputation it seems)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the class object while evaluating through `MVEL`.

1.) `SomeClass` is created

2.) `map.put("obj", myObj);` added to `HashMap`

3.) `MVEL.eval(exp,map)` need to evaluate

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass myObj = new SomeClass();
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("obj", myObj);
        MVEL.eval("System.out.println(\"I am inside main method\");obj.method1();",map);
    }

    public static void method1() {
        System.out.println("I am inside method 1");
    }
```

**output**

```
I am inside main method
I am inside method 1
```

Comment: i already did that but it doesn't reflect..i am new here. looks like i need to gain some 15 points(reputation) or something so that my vote is visible to the public..

Comment: If i want to add argments to method1() where the arguments will be available to me at runtime. how do i do it? Is it possible?

Comment: @Anuj Better as a knew question with complete info in question itself, instead of comments

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150207/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-function-written-inside-an-mvel-expression

Comment: I need a help. U there?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to call your own method in MVEL. First way like @Ankur Singhal's answer. And another way is use ParserContext.

Here is the Class

```
public class CalcHelper {
    public static int add(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Use ParserContext to import the Class to MVEL.

```
ParserContext parserContext = new ParserContext();
parserContext.addImport(CalcHelper.class.getSimpleName(), CalcHelper.class);
```

Then you can call static method of the Class in your expression.

```
Serializable s = MVEL.compileExpression("CalcHelper.add(1,2)", parserContext);
MVEL.executeExpression(s, parserContext);
```