# How to pass arguments to a function written inside an MVEL expression?

Tags: mvel

I have a JAVA class that has two methods. The first one is the main method and the second one is method1().

Let's say the following is the class:

```
public class SomeClass() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass myObj = new SomeClass();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("obj", myObj);
    MVEL.eval("System.out.println(\"I am inside main method\");obj.method1();",map);
  }
  public static void method1(List<String> listOfStrings){
    System.out.println("I am inside method 1");
  }
}
```

Now as you can see in the expression, to call method1, I need to pass a list as arguments. How to do that? What changes are required in the expression? What if I want to pass dynamic arguments in my program?

Comment: have a look at the answer, should solve your purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `List` or have it coming from some other source as an argument.

> Only thing you need to take care is to put inside the `map` object,
>   which used by `MVEL` for evaluation.

Need to pass list as mentioned -> `obj.method1(myList);`

**Working Code Below**

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass myObj = new SomeClass();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("obj", myObj);

        List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfStrings.add("my ");
        listOfStrings.add("List ");
        listOfStrings.add("is printing");

        map.put("obj", myObj);
        map.put("myList", listOfStrings);

        MVEL.eval("System.out.println(\"I am inside main method\");obj.method1(myList);",map);
    }

    public static void method1(List<String> listOfStrings) {
        System.out.println("I am inside method 1");
        for (String s : listOfStrings) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
I am inside main method
I am inside method 1
my List is printing
```

Comment: Thanks much. Works fine.

Comment: @Anuj please upvote as well both the answers, now you can

Comment: I need a help. U there?